# accept duplicate keys from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary

The following is a snippet of dataframe I have:

```
    node    group
0   28  1
167 28  2
```

I want to create a dictionary like structure from the above dataframe

and want to have something like

```
{28:1}
{28:2}
```

I tried to create it via

```
groupDict=groupTest.to_dict(orient='index')
```

which generates

```
{0: {'node': 28, 'group': 1}, 167: {'node': 28, 'group': 2}}
```

which is valid pandas way. But How would I generate

```
{28:1}
{28:2}
```

**Potentional solution as advised in comments below by  anky_91**:

```
df.groupby('node')['group'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: a dictionary can never have duplicate keys, that is not implemented in python yet

Comment: I am aware of that, but do you think there is a workaround?

Comment: save the values as a list ,? `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: No, it does not work to this data strucutre. I am trying to pass dictionary to networkX : nx.set_node_attributes

Comment: `df.groupby('node')['group'].agg(list).to_dict()` works in the given example

Comment: Yes, I think this is a progress. thanks anky_91